# For facebook I am using flutter_facebook_login plugin in flutter but still getting login again issue

Tags: flutter

For Facebook log in, I am using the flutter_facebook_login plugin. After successful login I am loading the Facebook profile URL then that page again shows to log in again.

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using "[flutter_facebook_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth)" instead of "flutter_facebook_login", as the latter one hasn't been updated in over 2 years, while the first one has constant maintenance, so the chance of letting you down or getting deprecated is lower.